# Zend Framework 2 "select where not in"

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2

I have this simple query where I have a `$posts` Array that contains IDs of certain posts. And I am selecting the files associated with these posts basically:

```
        ->from(
            ['DO' => 'DOCUMENT']
        )
        ->columns(
            [
                'POST_ID',
                'FILENAME'
            ]
        )
        ->where('DO.FILENAME LIKE "%'.$format.'%"')
        ->where(['DO.POST_ID' => $posts])
        ->order('DO.FILENAME DESC');
```

Now I want to select the files that are not related to these posts. So I need to do opposite of this:

```
        ->where(['DO.POST_ID' => $posts])
```

I cannot figure out how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `NOT IN` operation

```
   ->from(
            ['DO' => 'DOCUMENT']
        )
        ->columns(
            [
                'POST_ID',
                'FILENAME'
            ]
        )
        ->where('DO.FILENAME LIKE "%'.$format.'%"')
        ->where->addPredicate(new Zend\Db\Sql\Predicate\Expression('DO.POST_ID NOT IN (?)', array($posts)))
        ->order('DO.FILENAME DESC');
```

Comment: It doens't work :( It says `Call to undefined method Zend\Db\Sql\Where::order()` if I put your solution in there.

Comment: Move the `->order()` method on the `select->order()` and not on the `where->order()`. I can;t give you the full correct code for this since You didn't posted it.

Answer (score 0):

use Zend\Db\Sql\Predicate\NotIn;

```
$adapter = $this->tableGateway->getAdapter();
$sql = new Sql($adapter);
$select = $sql->select();
$select->from('produto');
$select->where->addPredicate->notIn('DO.POST_ID', [1,3,5]);
$select->order('status ASC');
$selectStr = $sql->getSqlStringForSqlObject($select);
echo $selectStr;
$results = $adapter->query($selectStr, $adapter::QUERY_MODE_EXECUTE);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).